# Export all MATLAB images in one go

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Code: https://pastebin.com/6MWsmaJF

Essentially, I've created a function in Matlab which spits out around 200 images.

How do I save all of these images in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to download a function from the file exchange,
here are some you can try and maybe quickly modify if necessary

https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32514-saveall
.eps format (should be adjustable to png)

https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43402-savefigures 
all figures in 1 .mat file

https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28312-save-figures
all current plots as, .emf, .fig, .png or eps

good luck and let me know if you need help

Comment: @JeremyFeng if this helps you, please upvote it. If it solves your problem, please accept it. If you're having trouble and need help, please respond and ask.